# Why are processes running on android emulator not showing up in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, process, ddms

I am using eclipse to launch an app in the android emulator. When I open the DDMS perspective, the devices tab shows the emulator process, however it does not show any other processes running on the emulator - I was expecting to see an entry for the app. The app has started successfully on the same emulator ( no other emulators are running ).

Is there any special configuration required for the emulator to allow processes to be seen by DDMS? I am running the app with SET_DEBUG_APP permission in manifest, and attribute debuggable set to true.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have selected the device or emulator you are monitoring. If nothing is selected it will not show anything. Usually the list of devices should be on the left top side of the DDMS view. I hope this can be a quick fix to your problem.

Comment: It worked after restarting Eclipse. The devices tab now shows emulator processes, and the debugger attaches to the app.